# Is there any mechanical digestion that occurs once food/chyme enters the small intestine?

Tags: homework, digestive-system, gastroenterology

Does mechanical digestion occur in small intestines and, if so, how does it occur? I found some sources that say digestion happens mechanically and chemically in the small bowel, and others that say it only happens chemically? Also, does chemical digestion only occur with acids (e.g. HCl) instead of enzymes, or does it occur with enzymes?

Answer (score 1):

I believe in small intestine peristalsis is sometimes counted as mechanical digestion as the food is moved along the digestive tract. Chemical digestion occurs with enzymes secreted from the pancreas.

https://www.smartlivingnetwork.com/digestive/b/mechanical-and-chemical-digestion/ - source